# ng-model doesnt update values

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, updates, angularjs-ng-model

I am developing an ionic app based on angular 1 and ionic 1, I have two input boxes with `ng-model` property set. Basically I want to change value of the other input box if either of their values are changed. The problem is that it works fine, when I change value in input-box-1, the value in input-box-2 changes, but the moment I change input-box-2, it doesn't reflect the change in input-box-1 and vice-versa.

I tried console logging the values, the changes happen bt thy dont get reflected.

Find the code Snippets here

```js
$scope.updateValues = function(option,values) {
    switch (option) {
      case "msrp_gp_parsent":
        $scope.msrp_gp_parsent = values;
        $scope.averagecost = (Math.abs((values - 100) * $scope.msrp_price)) / 100;
        $scope.standardcost = Math.abs((100 * $scope.averagecost) / ($scope.msrp_gp_parsent - 100));
        break;

      case "averagecost":
        $scope.averagecost = values;
        productDetailsDataFactory.getProductDetails().Pricing.AverageCost = values;
        $scope.msrp_gp_parsent = (($scope.msrp_price - values) / $scope.msrp_price) * 100;
        break;
      default:
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" ng-model="averagecost" name=""
       ng-keyup="updateValues('averagecost',averagecost)">
<input type="number"
       ngkeyup="updateValues('msrp_gp_parsent',msrp_gp_parsent)" />
```

Comment: Can you please add code snippets?. Is both text box are under same controller?

Comment: This is incomplete question.

Comment: you want to get textbox 2 values from textbox 1 right?

Comment: Make one fiddle and post your code this not right way to post codes

Comment: initially if i change either of the first say e.g averagecost , it changes the gp percent , but the moment i change gp percent box , it doesnt reflect change in average cost box , and vice versa happens

Comment: @MohanRam ... yes i added the snippets

Comment: Is it normal that ng-keyup is written twice?

Comment: Can you remove your ng-model and try it out

Comment: @RamsingNadeem it isnt written twice , its there for two different inputs

Comment: @MohanRam bt ng-model is used to bind the value with the variables in the controller. how will data binding happen without ng-model ??

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to do. My fiddle My fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/mohanramphp/nksqw5vb/13/ will show you what you need

Comment: @MohanRam Ok , so i checked your fiddle , but thats not what i want , i have two input boxes , each having their own value , and each one haveing a function on their ng-keyup event. If i change the value of one textbox , it does some calculations and updates the value of second textbox accordingly and vice versa. The problem is after changing one text box innitially(be it any of the two) it works fine as expected , bt the moment i change the next one , both stop updating the values. The scope variables associated with them get updated by changes no more reflect.

Comment: @MohanRam , see i update your fiddle  , i want exact that fuctionality in my ionic app . but it seems not to be working.

Comment: The second [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) directive is missing a hyphen. The second input is missing an [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive. The code should use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive instead of `ng-keyup`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/faizan_naseer/nksqw5vb/17/ chk this @georgeawg

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/faizan_naseer/nksqw5vb/17/ @MohanRam , this is wht i m taking about

Answer (score 0):

The [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) directive is fighting the [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive.

Replace the [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) directive with the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="averagecost"
       ̶n̶g̶-̶k̶e̶y̶u̶p̶ ng-change="updateValues('averagecost',averagecost)" />
<input type="number" ng-model="msrp_gp_parsent"
       ̶n̶g̶-̶k̶e̶y̶u̶p̶ ng-change="updateValues('msrp_gp_parsent',msrp_gp_parsent)" />
```

Both [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) put keyup event listeners on the element and there is no guarantee which code will be executed first. The [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive is integrated with the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and will properly execute only after the [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) value changes by user input.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues are here

1. Issue is you are using input type as **number** and you use key up event.
2. need to handle NaN in your code. If user type "-" its not an number.

---

Solution for #1 is - Keyup event will not be triggered when you use the spinner. Use change event instead.

Solution for #2 is - handle NaN in your code.

```
Fiddle forked from yours to show - https://jsfiddle.net/mohanramphp/1ehf49he/24/
```

Comment: Thanks @MohanRam for the solutions bt :(
i did the same procedure , bt i dont know what the heck is wrong with it... it doesnt seem to work at all.The problem is as it was.

Comment: Please create fiddle with ionic 1 and show your usecase there. I will help you to resolve.